# How to download a file to assets/www/ in android app?

Tags: android

So, I'm writing an android app and I want it to display information in webView, so I've got it displaying a simple local .html file in `assets/www` and that all works, but suppose I want to change the info, perhaps add something, how could I have the app download the file from, say, Dropbox and put it into `assets/www`? Just something like:

```
if (isOnline()) {
            download("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/0000000/index.html", "assets/www")
}
else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection, this information might be out of date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have the `isOnline()` function written and working, just need the download function, but I'm not sure where to start.

Edit, I've tried this so far:

```
if (isOnline()) { 
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://db.tt/WyAqN9r0");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String FILENAME = "tutortrusthandbook.html";
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    fos.write(str.getBytes());
                }
                in.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception Info " +     e.getCause(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.loadUrl("file://tutortrusthandbook.html");
```

But I'm not sure if it has managed anything because I don't know how to display the file now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could I have the app download the file from, say, Dropbox and put it into assets/www?

You can't. Assets are read-only at runtime. Save the downloaded file to internal storage (`getFilesDir()`) and load that into the `WebView`, falling back to your copy in assets if you do not have the downloaded update.